# My code is called within $document.ready but seems to be run before the DOM is loaded. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a script in my head as follows:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'></script>
<script>
    function editdoc(){
        document.getElementById("editme").innerHTML = "hello world";
    }

    $(document).ready(editdoc());
</script>
```

The body consists solely of a properly named div.

Now, when I pass this to the browser, Chrome gives me the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` error.

This error does not occur if I move this script into the body, or if use an anonymous function.  I think that means the function is being executed before the DOM is ready.

[This](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) says named functions should work the same as anonymous functions when called by $(document).ready.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling your function immediately rather than passing a reference.  You should be using this without the `()` after `editdoc`:

```
$(document).ready(editdoc);
```

What you were doing was calling the function immediately with `editdoc()` and passing the return value from that to `$(document).ready()`.  Thus, your observation that the function was getting called immediately.

Anytime, you put `()` after a function name or definition, you are telling the JS interpreter to execute it right now.  If you just pass the name of a function, then you are passing a reference (like a pointer) and the function you're passing it to can then execute it later which is what you want in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with you script is that you are executing the function. It should be like this.

You should change this

```
$(document).ready( editdoc() );
```

to this

```
$(document).ready( editdoc );
```

Answer (score 1):

do this instead:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function editdoc(){
            document.getElementById("editme").innerHTML = "hello world";
        }
        editdoc();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i don't think this is a good answer because it doesn't help explain the behaviour, and it solves the problem by creating a named function with the same scope as an anonymous function, which might not suit my needs.